# Difference between SCmd.readSerial() and Serial.read()

Tags: python, arduino

Currently I'm trying to Send information from python to Arduino through the serial port.

I manage this using only one letter `Serial.read()` 'P' and executing an action on my Arduino with the following code.

Arduino code:

```
#define arduinoLED 12   // Arduino LED on board

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(arduinoLED, OUTPUT);     // Configure the onboard LED for output
  digitalWrite(arduinoLED, LOW);   // default to LED off
 }

void loop() {
// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
//delay (20000);
//char comein=Serial.read();
//Serial.println(comein);
char *arg = "hello";
if (Serial.read()== 'P'){


digitalWrite(arduinoLED, HIGH);
delay(5000);
}
else {
digitalWrite(arduinoLED, LOW);
Serial.println("Hello World");
}
}
```

Python code:

```
ser.open()
ser.is_open

my_string='P'
my_string_as_bytes=str.encode(my_string)
print(my_string_as_bytes)
ser.write(my_string_as_bytes)
```

This works well and turn my LED on but how could I manage more then one letter for the command for example 'P1 2018' for the led to turn on?

But my real problem is that I try to do exactly the same thing, using the same Python code, but using `SCmd.readSerial()` to read the information in Arduino such as the following:

Arduino code:

```
 #include <SerialCommand.h>

 #define arduinoLED 12   // Arduino LED on board

 SerialCommand SCmd;   // The demo SerialCommand object

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(arduinoLED, OUTPUT);     // Configure the onboard LED for output
  digitalWrite(arduinoLED, LOW);   // default to LED off


  SCmd.addCommand("P1", process_command1); // Converts two arguments to integers and echos them back
  SCmd.addCommand("P", relay1_on);       // Turns Relay1 on
  SCmd.addDefaultHandler(unrecognized);  // Handler for command that isn't matched  (says "What?")
  Serial.println("Ready");
  }

  void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  SCmd.readSerial();     // We don't do much, just process serial commands


 }

 void relay1_on()
{
  digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
  Serial.println(3000);
  delay(3000);
  digitalWrite(12, LOW);
 }

void process_command1()
{
  int aNumber = 5;
  char *arg = "hello";

  Serial.println("We're in process_command");
  arg = SCmd.next();
  int OhmPosition = atoi(arg); //will return only numbers
  arg = SCmd.next();
  int relay = atoi(arg); //will return only numbers
  arg = SCmd.next();
  int opentime = atoi(arg); //will return only numbers

  Serial.println(OhmPosition);
  Serial.println(relay);
  Serial.println(opentime);
  }
```

As you can see, their is Serial command, responding to 'P' which is the same example as above but it doesn't work for some reason and don't understand why. Any idea?

And the second Serial command is 'P1' which is where I would like to get at the end, so I could send from Python something like:

Python code:

```
my_string6 = 'P1'+str(actions_time_[0][0] )+' '+str(actions_time_[0][1])+' '+str(actions_time_[0][2]))
my_string_as_bytes=str.encode(my_string6)
print(my_string_as_bytes)
ser.write(my_string_as_bytes)
output looks like this=> b'P1 150.0 5.0 2000.0 '
```

To enable me to start the P1 command and send values, to be saved in  `OhmPosition`, Relay, Time which will be separated by a space, as the goal is to pilot a small electrical automate.

I would be very please to have your support on theses couples of point related to each other.

Answer (score 0):

How can your program tell the difference between receiving the "P1" command and receiving the "P" command followed by some random "1"

You code seems to rely on a library that isn't a standard part of the Arduino install.  You should provide a link to where you got the SerialCommand class.

Comment: Hi Delta_G, the library used for the SCmd command is the following: https://github.com/scogswell/ArduinoSerialCommand

Comment: The program reconize 'P' or 'P1' as it is define in the SCmd.addCommand section of the arduino code in the void setup()

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks to Skarab i've found my answer, the main problem was that i didn't have "\r\n" at the end of my command.